# How do I sync Adblock Plus filters?

Tags: browser-addons, firefox-extensions, adblock

I use Adblock Plus at work and in two home PCs. Many times I'll block an advert on a page, or create a custom filter on one machine, and then have to block it again on the other machines.

Is there a way to ensure changes to one instance will be synchronized to the others?

Comment: I have been thinking about using dropbox, but I don't think I can create a "hotlink" that points to the *current* version of a shared file, only to a certain revision of it. I have yet to test to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of a file synchronization tool and an HTTP server will do the trick:

[image]

First, create a synched folder on all the computers where you use ADBlock Plus. Place an empty text file on that folder, and put `[Adblock Plus 2.0]` as the first line of the file. Copy all your custom filters to this file.

Now start an HTTP server on the machine (you can have it blocked by firewall, as we will use only localhost), and have it serve the folder where the file resides.

Finally, add a new filter subscription and set its address as `http://localhost/<yourfilename>`.

For the file sync, [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/) is a great tool, and it runs on Windows, Linux and mac. For the HTTP protocol, in Linux apache is the most popular server. In Windows I use a nice little app called [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/).

> A far more lightweight solution than Apache could be Python with SimpleHTTPserver (which is included in Python - no need to install extra stuff).
>
> 1. [Download and install Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
> 2. Access your directory with CMD (Windows) / Terminal (Unix)
> 3. Start serving the directory with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` (or a port you prefer)

Comment: Maybe running an HTTP server is too complex. But I can't think of a simpler solution. An alternative is using git on all computers and hosting the file on github, that offers free hosting, but I don't thing git fits in the "simpler" category...

Comment: If you only use Firefox, see my own answer. It's definitely simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only Firefox, see [this blog post](https://adblockplus.org/development-builds/firefox-sync-support-added). You'll need to both enable Firefox Sync and also enable "Sync Adblock Plus settings". I've never tried this sync system. It's supposed to work on both desktop and mobile.

If you're using Google Chrome, you may have to go with That Brazilian Guy's answer.